# How to Concacenate $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to a string

Tags: php

This is my code,

```
## GET REQUEST POSTING TO PAGE ( /example.php?name=something )##

## Expected Output : something

$var = '$_'.strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);// concatenating with '$_'


var_dump($var."['name']");             

echo '--<br>';

var_dump($var['name']);          

echo '--<br>';


print_r($var."['name']");    //not working     

echo '--<br>';

print_r($var['name']);     //not working
```

Any idea how to make this work ? what is the correct way ?

Comment: Just use `$_REQUEST` if you don't care if they're either posting or getting.

Comment: Actually I am creating a class for request handling, can't use $_REQUEST , as I am validating the method of request also thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double $

```
$var = "_" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

var_dump($$var);
```

But this is "dirty hack"

For good code use if or switch for init variable.

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
  case "POST":
   $var = $_POST;
  break;
  case "GET":
  default:
   $var = $_GET;
  break;
}
```

Comment: that was great , but I wanted to keep it simple without switch , can I use your dirty hack :) like this `$myarray = $$var;

print_r($myarray['name']);` Is it recommended ?